# How To Get user birthday Info graph api

Tags: php

I want get user DOB info using Facebook graph API. I got full dob but i need only Day and month

```
$graph_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,name,gender,location,birthday&access_token=" . $accessToken;
$user = json_decode(get_html($graph_url));

echo $user->birthday
```

The output is `MM/DD/YYYY` any way to get only Month and days.
 Thanks.

Comment: The output is in letters like Aug/Fri  i need in numbers like 8/5

Comment: ceck out the date manual of php . it's easy `echo date('m/d',strtotime( $user->birthday));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that you want number like `8/5` from your birthday that is coming. So you have to do simply:-

```
echo date('m/d',strtotime( $user->birthday));
```

To check date formats:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php